# How do I mirror what I am doing on one part/side of the mesh onto the other?

Tags: edit-mode, mirror

I am trying to make a symmetrical mesh were everything I do on one side get mirrored onto the opposite side (opposite axis) side

I came across many tutorials explaining how to mirror what's on one mesh onto another but these are from pre 2.8 and what I neeed is for the same mesh to be mirrored just on different sides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to add Mirror modifier to your object. As mirror center you can use object origin point on any other object by select it in Mirror Object.

[image: mirror edit]

You can adjust object origin using `Object` > `Tranform` > `Affect only` > `Origins`

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know about the mirror modifier but it only works for me if I select another object for it to be mirrored not the mesh selected, any way to overcome this?

Comment: Updated the answer with Affect Only origin adjustment. Also You can create an empty at desired mirror center and set it as Mirror object at Modifier, as mentioned above.